# Can I mount two different folders in one EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-efs

I have already mounted AWS EFS one folder in EC2 instance. I want to mount another one folder in same AWS EFS. Is this possible?

Comment: No, I have used a s3 bucket. If you know the solution, please update

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a Symbolic Link.

```
    mkdir -p /mnt/efs
    echo "${FileSystem}.efs.${AWS::Region}.amazonaws.com:/   /mnt/efs   nfs4    defaults" >> /etc/fstab
    mount -a
    ln -s /var/www/html/media /mnt/efs/media
    ln -s /var/www/html/var /mnt/efs/var
```

First your create a root directory for the mount point (`/mnt/efs`). Them you mount the FileSystem in this directory (`/mnt/efs`).
Now for example, if you want to map `/var/www/html/media` create a symbolic link pointing to the mounted point  (`ln -s /var/www/html/media /mnt/efs/media`). This will create a folder in `/mnt/efs/media`.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to mount two different directories under file mount system. Initially in order to access your efs just mount a EFS root under your instance using the command

```
sudo mount -t efs fs-id:/ /home/efs
```

Then create subdirectories under the `/home/efs` folder for example let's have two subdirectories under `/home/efs` namely images and data.

Now you can mount two directories in your which is likely to be under `/var/www/html/images` and `/var/www/html/data` by adding the below in `fstab` file which will be under `/etc/`

```
fs-id:/images /var/www/html/images efs defaults,_netdev 0 0

fs-id:/data /var/www/html/data efs defaults,_netdev 0 0
```

And reboot your instance. Whatever changes in `/var/www/html/data` will gets reflected in `fs-id:/data` folder also the same applies for image folder also hope this helps. Initially you need to setup `efs-utils` in your instance.

Answer (score 0):

I created symbolic link and it reflects in both sym link and main folder but does not reflect in another mounted server